# Best way to render multiple child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started learning ReactJS and am curious to know the best practice to rendering multiple different child components. What is the right way and most efficient way to do so? This is my current render function;

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Display
                image={this.state.professional.image}
                username={this.state.professional.username}
            />
            <div className="container">
                <Navbar
                    brand_name={!!this.state.professional.brand_name}
                    username={!!this.state.professional.username}
                    description={!!this.state.professional.description}
                    menu={!!this.state.professional.menu}
                    reviews={!!this.state.reviews}
                    photos={!!this.state.professional.photos}
                    email={!!this.state.professional.email}
                    address={!!this.state.professional.service_addresses}
                />
                <section className="artist-page">
                    <div className="container">
                        <About
                            description={this.state.professional.description}
                            accolades={this.state.professional.accolades}
                            cancellation={this.state.professional.lead_time_cancellation}
                            rules={this.state.professional.service_rules}
                            faqs={this.state.professional.faqs}
                        />
                        {(this.state.professional.menu || this.state.professional.offers)
                            &&
                        <Services
                            services={this.state.professional.menu}
                            offers={this.state.offers}
                        />}
                        {!!this.state.photos && <Portfolio photos={this.state.photos} />}
                        {!!this.state.reviews && <Reviews reviews={this.state.reviews} score={this.state.professional.rating_overall_stats} count={this.state.professional.review_count} />}
                        {(!!this.state.professional.email || !!this.state.professional.address) && <Contact
                            address={this.state.professional.service_addresses[0]}
                            name={!!this.state.professional.brand_name ? this.state.professional.brand_name : this.state.professional.username}
                        />}
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}
```

Comment: This looks fine, pretty much how you render stuff in React. Any particular part you're concerned about?

Comment: Do you ask, how it can be refactored?

Comment: @Jayce444 I'm concerned on its scalability, and curious how complex react apps actually render their components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Think about what needs to be a `state` and what should be `props`.

It seems like this parent component that you pasted here is storing information of all the children as state, before passing down to its children as props.

Are you sure this parent needs to know anything about `username`, `description`, `menu`, etc of `<Navbar>`? If it doesn't, then save them as Navbar's own states.

#### You can pass down entire `this.state.professional` object as props.

```
<About professional = {this.state.professional}/>
```

Then in your About component, you can take apart the object and use it accordingly:

```
<p>{ this.props.professional.description }</p>
```

#### You can consider destructuring for readability

```
const {description, rules} = this.state.professional

return (
  <About description={description} rules={rules}/>
)
```

#### Fix your <Navbar>

Personally I think that it looks weird and unreadable when you pass down `boolean` like that. You can consider this:

```
<Navbar reviews={this.state.reviews} {...this.state.professional} />
```

Then do your boolean evaluation inside Navbar component itself, here's a few example:

```
const {username, description, reviews} = this.props
<p>{ reviews || 'No reviews' }</p>
<p>{ username ? formatName(username) : "" }</p>
<p>{ description && 'Has description!' }</p>
```

Comment: Very detailed, thanks for the explanation and the break down!